# Tablets boots into portrait mode when should be in landscape

Tags: android, boot, landscape-portrait

Android tablets boots into portrait mode briefly before switching to landscape.

I have the default orientation as landscape and auto rotate off.

The tablets are Samsung tab S2's they are rooted, so i was wondering if there was a way of forcing them to boot into landscape by changing system files or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe better asked on Android Enthusiasts (but check their guidelines first): [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/67649/115134) talks of _part_ of the boot sequence being (un-rotatable) images; [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/10808/115134) appears to be asking almost the opposite (make a tablet boot in portrait).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as this question will better suit on Android Enthusiast site